# Google Glass unable to detect device compatibility with latest version

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I've upgraded my Glass to XE22 and my SDK manger is up to date. I've set up my project for GDK Preview [Android 4.4.2] and my project settings are `android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="22"`.

However, I'm getting an error:

```
No Launcher activity found!
The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
Performing sync
Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
```

Do I have something set up incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

Use 19 for both minimum and target ... the "22" in `XE22` does not refer to an `Android` `SDK` version for Glass.

```
android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="19"
```